# Where is the Riddler in Arkham Asylum?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I took all the trophies and enigmas. After the last enigma I got an incoming transmission (if I understood, it was to tell me where Edward Nigma is located) but I didn't understand perfectly.

On the map there is nothing. So where is the Riddler?

Comment: I got his location when I had all but three riddles solved, all maps completed but one (sewers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My understanding was that he wasn't actually on the island, and when Batman collects all the riddles he deciphers the location and sends the police there. I recall hearing Edward Nigma being arrested over the radio transmission.

A slightly disappointing conclusion to the long search for riddles, perhaps :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the enigma has been freed from Arkham island as his cell is empty, but freshly grafittied . He devised a plan that can be controlled remotely, so he can see what secrets The Batman solves from Gotham if freed from custody.